# SELECT ? FROM table WHERE id = ? not working correctly

Tags: php, mysqli

I've got a little question. I want to get specific information out of my database via mysqli query:

```
public function get_searchorder_single_information($soid, $information) {

        global $mysqli;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM pr_hr_searchorders WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $information, $soid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $result;

        $stmt->close();

    }
```

In my example, `$information` is set 'job', but it can have other values, too (e.g. 'salary'). When I try to use my query with this variable, echo outputs just 'job' and not the value that is saved in my database. When I write 'job' instead of the '?', echo outputs the correct value.

So now I could make a function for each information I search, but this would end in spaghetti code. So I ask you if there is any possibility to use my search query like above with correct output. How would I do that?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english writing.

Comment: Please read all the docs (including the notes) of the functions/methods you use. In specific `mysqli::prepare()`

Comment: Closed this question in hope that the answer won't do too much harm

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value. However, they are not
>   allowed for identifiers (such as table or column names), in the select
>   list that names the columns to be returned by a SELECT statement, or
>   to specify both operands of a binary operator such as the = equal
>   sign. The latter restriction is necessary because it would be
>   impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not allowed to
>   compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general, parameters are
>   legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements, and not in
>   Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Modify your code :

```
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT $information FROM pr_hr_searchorders WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $soid);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped :-)!

Comment: @DanielWohlgemuth I **hope** you are aware of the fact that this solution is **wide** open to **SQL injection**

Comment: I know but it's not the subject , i just fix his usage , there is a lot of things to do if you want correct all his code conception

Answer (score -3):

Change your code to

```
public function get_searchorder_single_information($soid, $information) {

        global $mysqli;
        $query = "SELECT".$information." FROM pr_hr_searchorders WHERE id = ?"
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('si', $soid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($result);
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $result;

        $stmt->close();

    }
```

Then you will get the desired result

Comment: You can also use back-ticks to quote field names which is actually sufficient escaping.

Comment: @apokryfos which is actually NOT

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @YourCommonSense citation needed (i'm assuming you mean backticks in the field name)

Comment: @apokryfos here you go, [An SQL injection against which prepared statements won't help. Adding backticks](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#backticks)

Comment: @YourCommonSense there's something off about citing your self for something you said. That being said, even that resource does verify that backticks are enough if you just double up the inner backticks.

Comment: @apokryfos Q.E.D.